# Proving if this integral converges over $[0,\infty)$, two of its coefficients must have the same sign.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_a^b R(x)dx$$
, where $R(x)$ is a rational function:
$$R(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
with
$$P(x)=p_mx^m+p_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+p_1x+p_0$$
$$Q(x)=q_nx^n+q_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+q_1x+q_0$$

> Can we prove that if the integral $I$ from 0 to $\infty$ is convergent, then $q_n$ and $q_0$ must have the same sign?

I believe the transformation may help:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{tdt}{(2t+1)(t+1)^2}=\int_0^1\frac{xdx}{x+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ is relatively prime.
Let $Q(x)\equiv(x-x_0)^r q(x)$, where $x_0\ge0$, $r\ge1$ and $q(x_0)\neq 0$.
Let $c>x_0$ be a real number such that $Q(x)\neq0$ for $x\in(x_0,c]$.
Then, $\int_{x_0}^c {R(x)dx}$ (and so does $\int_0^\infty {R(x)dx}$) diverges as $\int_{x_0}^c {\frac{P(x_0)}{(x-x_0)^r q(x_0)}dx}$ diverges.
Hence, if $I$ converges from $0$ to $\infty$, $\frac{Q(x)}{q_n}$ has no non-negative roots and factorizes (in $\mathbb{R}$) into linear factors $(x+\alpha)$ with $\alpha>0$ and irreducible quadratic factors $(x^2+\beta x+\gamma)$, in which $\gamma>0$ as $\Delta<0$. Therefore, $\frac{q_0}{q_n}>0$ and they have the same sign.